# Single Page Application (Hot Towel)

Tags: c#, google-visualization, visual-studio-2013

I am using SPA with hot towel and trying to load google charts. When I try loading the package with the code

`google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart']});`

the entire screen goes blank. I want to use the data obtained from the database to build the chart so I run the method containing this code in the "attached" property of the vm.

How can I add google charts?

Comment: The google loader behaves strangely when called from within other functions - you can generally fix this by specifying the callback inline:  `google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawMyChart});`.

Comment: did not work. Same behavior

Comment: Can you update your post with the full javascript code?